# Child's gravity is ignored

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I have custom layout (eventually extends ViewGroup), which contains 2 ImageButtons and 1 custom view (extends SurfaceView). 
My problem is that`android:layout_gravity="center"` on my images is not working.
Furthermore it is not even show on the auto-complete in the xml editor

```
<com.technaim.elecbic.Circle
        android:id="@+id/action_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

```
 public class Circle extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static int PIXELS_TO_REMOVE = 4;

    private Paint circlePaint = null;
    private int parentWidth;
    private int parentHeight;
    private int centerX;
    private int centerY;
    private int radius;
    private RadialGradient lockDisplayGradient = null;
    private RadialGradient unlockDisplayGradient = null;

    public Circle(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void initializeMembers() {
        View parent = (View) getParent();

        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setDither(true);

        parentWidth = parent.getWidth() - PIXELS_TO_REMOVE;
        centerX = parentWidth / 2;
        parentHeight = parent.getHeight() - PIXELS_TO_REMOVE;
        centerY = parentHeight / 2;
        radius = getWidth() / 3;

        lockDisplayGradient = new RadialGradient(centerX, centerY, radius,
                getResources().getColor(R.color.green), getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.red), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        unlockDisplayGradient = new RadialGradient(centerX, centerY, radius,
                getResources().getColor(R.color.red), getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.green), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, this.circlePaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        initializeMembers();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    }

    public void changeToLockDisplay() {
        circlePaint.setShader(lockDisplayGradient);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void changeToUnlockDisplay() {
        circlePaint.setShader(unlockDisplayGradient);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        // MUST CALL THIS
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
    }
}
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainScreen" >

<com.technaim.elecbic.DragLayer
    android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.technaim.elecbic.Circle
        android:id="@+id/action_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_lock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lock"
        android:src="@drawable/lock"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_unlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/unlock"
        android:src="@drawable/unlock"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</com.technaim.elecbic.DragLayer>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_track_device"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/track_device" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE: 
Don't have any layout option on the children

```
    /*
 * This is a modified version of a class from the Android Open Source Project. 
 * The original copyright and license information follows.
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.technaim.elecbic;

import com.technaim.logic.DragController;
import com.technaim.logic.DragSource;
import com.technaim.logic.DropTarget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A ViewGroup that coordinates dragging across its dscendants.
 *
 * <p> This class used DragLayer in the Android Launcher activity as a model.
 * It is a bit different in several respects:
 * (1) It extends MyAbsoluteLayout rather than FrameLayout; (2) it implements DragSource and DropTarget methods
 * that were done in a separate Workspace class in the Launcher.
 */
public class DragLayer extends MyAbsoluteLayout 
    implements DragSource, DropTarget
{
    DragController mDragController;

    /**
     * Used to create a new DragLayer from XML.
     *
     * @param context The application's context.
     * @param attrs The attribtues set containing the Workspace's customization values.
     */
    public DragLayer (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setDragController(DragController controller) {
        mDragController = controller;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return mDragController.dispatchKeyEvent(event) || super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mDragController.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mDragController.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchUnhandledMove(View focused, int direction) {
        return mDragController.dispatchUnhandledMove(focused, direction);
    }

/**
 */
// DragSource interface methods

/**
  * This method is called to determine if the DragSource has something to drag.
  * 
  * @return True if there is something to drag
  */

public boolean allowDrag () {
    // In this simple demo, any view that you touch can be dragged.
    return true;
}

/**
 * setDragController
 *
 */

 /* setDragController is already defined. See above. */

/**
 * onDropCompleted
 *
 */

public void onDropCompleted (View target, boolean success)
{
    //toast ("DragLayer2.onDropCompleted: " + target.getId () + " Check that the view moved.");
}

/**
 */
// DropTarget interface implementation

/**
 * Handle an object being dropped on the DropTarget.
 * This is the where a dragged view gets repositioned at the end of a drag.
 * 
 * @param source DragSource where the drag started
 * @param x X coordinate of the drop location
 * @param y Y coordinate of the drop location
 * @param xOffset Horizontal offset with the object being dragged where the original
 *          touch happened
 * @param yOffset Vertical offset with the object being dragged where the original
 *          touch happened
 * @param dragView The DragView that's being dragged around on screen.
 * @param dragInfo Data associated with the object being dragged
 * 
 */

public void onDrop(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
        DragView dragView, Object dragInfo)
{
    View v = (View) dragInfo;
    /*toast ("DragLayer2.onDrop accepts view: " + v.getId ()
          + "x, y, xO, yO :" + new Integer (x) + ", " + new Integer (y) + ", "
          + new Integer (xOffset) + ", " + new Integer (yOffset));*/

    int w = v.getWidth ();
    int h = v.getHeight ();
    int left = x - xOffset;
    int top = y - yOffset;
    DragLayer.LayoutParams lp = new DragLayer.LayoutParams (w, h, left, top);
    this.updateViewLayout(v, lp);
}

public void onDragEnter(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
        DragView dragView, Object dragInfo)
{
}

public void onDragOver(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
        DragView dragView, Object dragInfo)
{
}

public void onDragExit(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
        DragView dragView, Object dragInfo)
{
}

/**
 * Check if a drop action can occur at, or near, the requested location.
 * This may be called repeatedly during a drag, so any calls should return
 * quickly.
 * 
 * @param source DragSource where the drag started
 * @param x X coordinate of the drop location
 * @param y Y coordinate of the drop location
 * @param xOffset Horizontal offset with the object being dragged where the
 *            original touch happened
 * @param yOffset Vertical offset with the object being dragged where the
 *            original touch happened
 * @param dragView The DragView that's being dragged around on screen.
 * @param dragInfo Data associated with the object being dragged
 * @return True if the drop will be accepted, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean acceptDrop(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
        DragView dragView, Object dragInfo)
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Estimate the surface area where this object would land if dropped at the
 * given location.
 * 
 * @param source DragSource where the drag started
 * @param x X coordinate of the drop location
 * @param y Y coordinate of the drop location
 * @param xOffset Horizontal offset with the object being dragged where the
 *            original touch happened
 * @param yOffset Vertical offset with the object being dragged where the
 *            original touch happened
 * @param dragView The DragView that's being dragged around on screen.
 * @param dragInfo Data associated with the object being dragged
 * @param recycle {@link Rect} object to be possibly recycled.
 * @return Estimated area that would be occupied if object was dropped at
 *         the given location. Should return null if no estimate is found,
 *         or if this target doesn't provide estimations.
 */
public Rect estimateDropLocation(DragSource source, int x, int y, int xOffset, int yOffset,
            DragView dragView, Object dragInfo, Rect recycle)
{
    return null;
}

/**
 */
// More methods

/**
 * Show a string on the screen via Toast.
 * 
 * @param msg String
 * @return void
 */


} // end class
```

Comment: pls post your xml code

Comment: post `DragLayer` code

Comment: DragLayer was added - pay attention it is code from a blog (don't remember which one) that was slightly changed for the specific app